# How to prevent "connection refused" with SOCKS on dataproc?

Tags: ssh, socks, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to set up a SOCKS connection to my dataproc spark cluster following [the Google Jupyter guide](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/tutorials/jupyter-notebook), but I keep getting "connection refused" errors after launching the browser, Chrome:

```
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 6: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 7: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 8: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 16: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 16: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 17: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 18: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 16: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 18: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 18: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 18: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

This happens with both `--proxy-server="socks5://localhost:1080"` and `--proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"`

Comment: Without the dynamic-forwarding flags, are you able to at least SSH into the master node directly, via `gcloud compute ssh <your-master-node>`?

Comment: Oh sure, I've been happily using Jupyter with port forwarding for a while. The only reason I am interested in SOCKS is to be able to access the SparkUI.

Comment: Do you have more details on your "connection refused" errors? Are those coming from a browser? Or are you using some other custom application against the socks connection?

Answer (score 3):

So, I'm not 100% sure where the "administratively prohibited" messages come from, but in my experience those have always been false alarms, and I see those `open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed` messages even when my socks proxy is functioning correctly as expected.

As for the actual problem, due to the way things like YARN bind their web services, I've gotten `Connection refused` if trying to access the YARN UI with `http://localhost:8088` instead of `http://<master-hostname>:8088`. This matches the behavior running `get` inside the cluster:

```
dhuo@dhuo-jupyter-m:~$ wget http://localhost:8124
...
Saving to: ‘index.html.13’

index.html.13                                                          100%[=============================================================================================================================================================================>]  11.41K  --.-KB/s   in 0s     

2016-07-15 23:26:25 (222 MB/s) - ‘index.html.13’ saved [11686/11686]

dhuo@dhuo-jupyter-m:~$ wget http://localhost:8088
--2016-07-15 23:26:28--  http://localhost:8088/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8088... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8088... failed: Connection refused.
dhuo@dhuo-jupyter-m:~$ wget http://`hostname`:8124
...
Saving to: ‘index.html.14’

index.html.14                                                          100%[=============================================================================================================================================================================>]  11.41K  --.-KB/s   in 0s     

2016-07-15 23:26:34 (260 MB/s) - ‘index.html.14’ saved [11686/11686]

dhuo@dhuo-jupyter-m:~$ wget http://`hostname`:8088
...
Saving to: ‘index.html.15’

index.html.15                                                          100%[=============================================================================================================================================================================>]  10.81K  --.-KB/s   in 0s     

2016-07-15 23:26:37 (248 MB/s) - ‘index.html.15’ saved [11067/11067]
```

As you can see, this is different from the Jupyter behavior (which I ran on port `8124`), where the Jupyter webapp works correctly resolving `localhost:8124` on the master. Since the name resolution with those linked instructions should be happening on the master, the browser's behavior resolving hosts will be the same as running `wget` in the node you've tunneled into.

So if you just use your master's hostname instead of localhost it should work.

Comment: The "administratively prohibited" messages only appear with 127.0.0.1